# Update MySQL database with PDO and Jquery/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I want to update user's data when user clicks a link in the page here is a link's structure.

```
<a href='#' class='a_bolum' data-fakulte='foo' data-bolumkodu='boo' data-bolum='bar'>bar</a>
```

Links are added with Jquery/AJAX.

profil_f.JS

```
   $bolumler.delegate('.a_bolum','click',function() {
        var secilen_fakulte = $(this).attr('data-fakulte');
        var secilen_bolum = $(this).data('bolum');
        var secilen_bolum_kodu = $(this).data('bolumkodu');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'profil-duzenle.php',
            data : 'bolumkodu='+secilen_bolum_kodu,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#yukleniyor").addClass('yukleniyor_goster');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $("#yukleniyor").removeClass('yukleniyor_goster');
            },
            success: function() {
                alert(secilen_bolum_kodu);
            }
        });

    });
```

secilen_fakulte, secilen_bolum and secilen_bolum_kodu are successfully assigned.

profil-duzenle.PHP

```
<?php
    require_once "../inc/baglanti.inc.php";
    require_once "../inc/fonksiyon.inc.php";

//  $fakulte =p("fakulte");
//  $bolum = p("bolum");
    $bolum_kodu = p("bolumkodu");
    $guncelle = true;


    if ($guncelle == true) {
        $s_id = $_SESSION["id"];
        $sql = "UPDATE uye SET uye_bolum_kodu = :uye_bolum_kodu WHERE uye_id = :uye_id";
        $profil_guncelle = $db_uye->prepare($sql);
        //$profil_guncelle->bindParam(':uye_fakulte',$fakulte,PDO::PARAM_STR,255);
        //$profil_guncelle->bindParam(':uye_bolum',$bolum,PDO::PARAM_STR,255);
        $profil_guncelle->bindParam(':uye_bolum_kodu',$bolum_kodu,PDO::PARAM_STR,10);
        $profil_guncelle->bindParam(':uye_id',$s_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $guncellendi = $profil_guncelle->execute(array(
            ':uye_bolum_kodu'=>$bolum_kodu,
            ':uye_id'=>$s_id
        ));

        if ($guncellendi) {
            $profil_sonuc[] = "<div class='profil_sonuc basarili'>Profil bilgilerini güncelledik. Anasayfaya gitmek için <a href='../profil.php'>tıkla</a></div>";
        } else {
            $profil_sonuc[] = "<div class='profil_sonuc hatali'>Profil bilgilerini güncellerken bir veritabanı hatasıyla karşılaştık. <a href='../geribildirim'>Geri Bildirim Gönder</a> veye tekrar dene</div>";
        }
    }

    echo $bolum_kodu;
?>
```

I tested just PHP part with sending form to profil-duzenle.php. I tried both method GET and POST . It works perfectly. Updates MySQL database. If I try it with ajax beforeSend, complete and success parts work. But updating part not working. profik-duzenle.php and profil_f.js are in same folder. What am i missing?

I don't know hot it works but here is network tab of firefox when i use ajax
[image: I don't know hot it works but here is network tab of firefox when i use ajax]

**Update:** 
I found out that $_POST[] variables are empty if i send them with ajax  but still don't know why

Comment: Is profil-duzenle.php in the same directory as the page that _loads_ profil_f.js? You could try using the full path from the web root and see if that clears it up.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes they are (index.php -loads js-, .profil_f.js, profil-duzenle.php) in the same folder (profil folder). I tried this `url: http://www.sitename.com/profil/profil-duzenle.php` but it didn't work either.